# Remove short words and characters from a string in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I have a string which could be like this:

```
NSString *string = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";
```

I want my result to be:

```
"Lorem Ipsum simply dummy printing typesetting industry"
```

My first idea:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"some regex magic" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:@"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [firstLine length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @fengd this should be customizable

Comment: @rmaddy http://pastebin.com/QX5GVwHz

Comment: check for the index path of the character @" "..

Comment: @TUNER88 Post the relevant code in your question so people can see it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSRegularExpression way:

```
NSString *text = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b\\w{1,4}\\b\\s?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"Result: %@", modifiedString);
```

Result:

```
Lorem Ipsum simply dummy printing typesetting industry
```

## **UPDATE**

Performance test **NSPredicate** vs **NSRegularExpression**

```
NSString *string = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";

// NSPredicate
NSDate *start1 = [NSDate date];
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
{
    NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 4"];
    NSArray *largerWords = [words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    NSString *filteredString = [largerWords componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
}
NSDate *finsh1 = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval executionTime1 = [finsh1 timeIntervalSinceDate:start1];
NSLog(@"Execution Time NSPredicate: %f", executionTime1);

// NSRegularExpression
NSDate *start2 = [NSDate date];
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b\\w{1,4}\\b\\s?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
}
NSDate *finsh2 = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval executionTime2= [finsh2 timeIntervalSinceDate:start2];
NSLog(@"Execution Time NSRegularExpression: %f", executionTime2);
```

**Result:**

```
Execution Time NSPredicate: 0.246003
Execution Time NSRegularExpression: 0.594555
```

**NSPredicate solution is much faster than NSRegularExpression**

Thanks @Alladinian for NSPredicate solution

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess there must be a gazillion solutions to this. Here is one of them:

```
NSString *string = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";
NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 4"];
NSArray *largerWords = [words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
NSString *filteredString = [largerWords componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"%@", filteredString);
// Outputs => Lorem Ipsum simply dummy text printing typesetting industry
```

Answer (score 2):

try (changing the >3 can decide the length of the word to be removed, in this case if you have less than 4 characters is removed):

```
 NSString *string = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";

NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

NSMutableString *modified = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(NSString *word in words){
    if([word length]>3){
        NSLog(@"Do something with big lengthy word: %@", word);
        [modified appendString:word];
        [modified appendString:@" "];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"This is a smaller word: %@", word);
    }

}
NSLog(@"Here is modified string : %@", modified);
```

output  `Here is modified string : Lorem Ipsum simply dummy text printing typesetting industry`

Comment: Why append an empty string if the word is to be ignored?

Comment: @TUNER88 this way is quite handy